# Where is my time machine?

Tags: the-sims-3, sims-3-ambitions

I have built a time machine, but it doesn't appear in my Sim's catalog. Where should it be?

Comment: I couldn't agree more! Where is my time machine?! I was promised a time machine!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unlike most other inventions, Time Machines don't appear in the Sim's inventory, instead they appear in the family inventory.

Go into the buy menu and access the family inventory to place it.